# Change circle radius dynamiclly when zoom in and out in Google Map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I wanna change the Circle radius when the map is zoomed in or out in Google Map to be scalable like FlutterMap.

can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it as you can see below but I am sure there is another Solution more effective than my solution

```
  static GoogleMapController? controller;
  double _radius = 400000; // you have to declare the Circle radius with this value
  int zoomLevel = 3;
  Future<void> radius() async {
    double zoomvalue = await controller!.getZoomLevel();
    int intZoomLevel = zoomvalue.toInt();
    if (intZoomLevel < 4 && zoomLevel != intZoomLevel) {
      zoomLevel = intZoomLevel;
      _radius = 400000;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (intZoomLevel > zoomLevel) {
      int fach = intZoomLevel - zoomLevel;
      zoomLevel = intZoomLevel;
      _radius = _radius / (2 * fach);
      setState(() {});
    } else if (intZoomLevel < zoomLevel) {
      int fach = zoomLevel - intZoomLevel;
      zoomLevel = intZoomLevel;
      _radius = _radius * (2 * fach);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) async {
    try {
      await radius();
    } catch (_) {}
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    GoogleMapPageState.controller = controller;
  }
```

Edit my solution for the enhancement

```
double radius = 400000;
  int zoomLevel = 3;
  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    try {
      double zoomvalue = position.zoom;
      int intZoomLevel = zoomvalue.toInt();
      if (intZoomLevel < 4 && zoomLevel != intZoomLevel) {
        zoomLevel = intZoomLevel;
        radius = 400000;
        setState(() {});
      } else if (intZoomLevel > zoomLevel) {
        int fach = intZoomLevel - zoomLevel;
        zoomLevel = intZoomLevel;
        radius = radius / (2 * fach);
        setState(() {});
      } else if (intZoomLevel < zoomLevel) {
        int fach = zoomLevel - intZoomLevel;
        zoomLevel = intZoomLevel;
        radius = radius * (2 * fach);
        setState(() {});
      }
    } catch (_) {}
  }
```

Comment: Scaling of zoom levels in google maps is done with powers of 2 - so I would expect to see `_radius = _radius / (pow(2,fach))` and similar for zoom in.  Is your scaling working for you as a multiple of 2?  (Applicable for zoom deltas > 2).

Comment: for me it work as i need when using ` radius = radius * (2 * fach);`